# How to convert arrays into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I'm trying to make an array of objects from several arrays.This is probably a very basic question, but I didn't find a proper way of doing it from searching online. :(

The original data I've got is

```
valueYes = [15,30,22,18,2,6,38,18];
valueNo = [23,75,45,12,45,9,17,23];
valueNotSure = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1];
```

What I want to achieve is an array like :

```
data = [object1, object2,.....]
```

Each object is made of :

```
object1 = {valueYes:15, valueNo:23,valueNotSure:1}
object2 = {valueYes:30, valueNo:75,valueNotSure:-1}
.......
```

my current code is a bit messy, which only return me an empty value of each key:

```
valueYes = [15,30,22,18,2,6,38,18];
valueNo = [23,75,45,12,45,9,17,23];
valueNotSure = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1];

var object1 = Object.create({}, { 
    myChoice: { value: function(myChoice) {for  (var i = 0; i < len; i++){return this.myChoice[i] = myChoice[i];} } } 

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming all your arrays have the same size:

```
valueYes = [15,30,22,18,2,6,38,18];
valueNo = [23,75,45,12,45,9,17,23];
valueNotSure = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1];

var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < valueYes.length; i++){
    data.push({
        valueYes: valueYes[i],
        valueNo: valueNo[i],
        valueNotSure: valueNotSure[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: ah, this is the thing I'm looking for, very clear! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like below;

```
var objs = valueYes.map(function (v, i) {
    return {
        valueYes: v,
        valueNo: valueNo[i],
        valueNotSure: valueNotSure[i]
    };
});
```

... this uses the [`map()` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and assumes that all the arrays are the same length...

Comment: Yeah, I considered `map`, but thought the loop might be clearer, given the OP's level...

Comment: Nice & elegant solution with .map()

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
var valueYes = [15,30,22,18,2,6,38,18];
var valueNo = [23,75,45,12,45,9,17,23];
var valueNotSure = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1];

var data = [];
valueYes.forEach(function(item, index) {
    data.push({ valueYes: valueYes[index], valueNo: valueNo[index], valueNotSure: valueNotSure[index] });
});

console.log(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/9t1y1zhk/

Comment: Why would you use `forEach` and `push` when `map` does exactly the same thing? And why would you use `valueYes[index]` when you already have it in `item`?

Comment: You need the index because you have to get the [index] of the other 2 arrays. The "item" references only values from the valueYes array. And I didn't thought about using .map(). I have also commented on Matt's post that use .map() is very elegant ;-)